# How to Disable celery tasks logs

Tags: scrapy, celery

i'm using celery to send task.

i want to see only 'received task ..' and 'Task .. succeeded' 
[image: spider logs on celery server]
but spider logs on celery server

how to disable task logs?

Answer (score 0):

From your picture i can see that this is debug logs. 
So, configure your logger properly or disable DEBUG mode.

Your screenshot doesn't give enough info about the frameworks/libs your are using, so i cannot advice anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script. `grep` logs you need to annother file per second.

```
grep -E 'received task|succeeded' celery.log >> task.log
```